# elliptic integral - gauss theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, elliptic-integrals

In order to proove Gauss theorem on elliptic integrals it's written :

For any couples $(a, b$), let us defines :
$$\displaystyle \mathcal{T}(a, b) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a^2+t^2)\cdot(b^2+t^2)}} \cdot \mathrm{d}t$$

we may notice that Lagrange's identity implies :
$$ (a^2+t^2)(b^2+t^2) = (at+bt)^2+(t^2-ab)^2$$
hence by setting $u = \frac{1}{2} (t-ab/t)$ we have :

$$ \displaystyle \mathcal{T}(a, b) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+b)^2 + (t-\frac{ab}{t})^2}} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{((a+b)^2+4u^2)(ab+u^2)}} = \mathcal{T}(\frac{a+b}{2}, \sqrt{ab})$$

I must say that I don't understand at all the last part, I mean : 
how do you get from :
$$\displaystyle \mathcal{T}(a, b) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+b)^2 + (t-\frac{ab}{t})^2}} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}$$ to $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{((a+b)^2+4u^2)(ab+u^2)}}$$ ? 
And how do you get that is is also equals to : $\mathcal{T}(\frac{a+b}{2}, \sqrt{ab})$.

This demonstrations can be found here : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view page $142$

Comment: As it is written: through the (Cauchy-Schlomilch) substitution $u=\frac{1}{2}\left(t-\frac{ab}{t}\right)$.

Comment: Ok but using this substition I don't get the same result

Comment: And what do you get?

Comment: I get that $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u+2ab} = \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}$ and hence In the square root, I get : $(u+2ab)^2$ and not $(u^2+ab)$

Comment: $u=\frac{1}{2}\left(t-\frac{ab}{t}\right)$ means $t=u-\sqrt{ab+u^2}$, so $dt = \left(1-\frac{u}{\sqrt{ab+u^2}}\right)\,du $ and $$\frac{dt}{t}=-\frac{du}{\sqrt{ab+u^2}}.$$

Comment: Ok, thank you. Still, in this you get : $\mathrm{d}t/t= -\frac{(\sqrt{ab+u^2}-u)^2}{\sqrt{ab+u^2} }\cdot \mathrm{d}u$, but how can you get rid of : $(\sqrt{ab+u^2}-u)^2$ ?

Comment: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{u}{g(u^2)}\,du = 0 $$ provided that the LHS makes sense. The integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval with respect to the origin cannot be anything else.

Comment: I think I understand now ! :) Thank you for your help, and your wonderful notes ! Do you know, where I can learn more about the Cauchy-Schlomilch substitution ?

Comment: Here we go, directly from the shoulders of giants (Glasser, in this case): https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2445

Comment: Thank you. The fact that : $t = u -\sqrt{ab+u^2}$ is not straightforward to me, can you provide the demonstration of this result ? :)

Comment: Solving $u=\frac{1}{2}\left(t-\frac{ab}{t}\right)$ with respect to $t$ is equivalent to solving a quadratic equation. I believe you have experienced it.

Comment: Omg, was trying to develop and it's just a quadratic equation... Time, to go to bed, thank you for you extreme patience